# Http headers in serverleass architecture

Tags: aws-lambda

I am using serverless architecture for my webbapplication. I wanred to implement http security headers.
Please let me know how to do it and also what values are specific to “content security policy” header interms of security.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please see How to Ask - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can add the security headers by using the Lambda@edge in your cloudfront distribution. Please have a look into the following blog to get an idea of how to implement this.
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/adding-http-security-headers-using-lambdaedge-and-amazon-cloudfront/